# Spring Security - Url with IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY but with credentials still specified (and unknow) is blocked by the framework

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I have a mapped url (of a rest api) in my security.xml with access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" set.

It works correctly if I call that endpoint with no credentials, but if I specify some basic auth one (Important!, not provisioned in Spring Users table on db, cause I don't want to be authenticated by the framework on that endpoint, but I need them for other uses later), spring security blocks the access.
I suppose the problem is that Spring correctly allows anonymous requests, but when I do it with unknow credentials the framework try to authenticate them anyway.

Is there a way to completely bypass spring security for a specific url?

Comment: Share your code, please
And what framework are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to completely bypass spring security for a specific
>   url?

Yes .You can configure the `WebSecurity` to ignore this URL:

```java
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
       .antMatchers("/foo-url");
}
```

Then spring security will not kick in to handle this URL.